# Multi company: child companies cannot view each others invoices

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-9

I have a parent company and some child companies. I want all my child companies to view all the customer invoices by all other child companies and administrator. Also if my child A receive a payment from child B it should be saved as A's cash but not in it's income. The same should be saved as B income but not its cash.

Comment: You haven't shown us your code, so we cannot possibly tell what the problem is...

Comment: We want to do these changes in developer mode. So what all changes are needed to be done in the settings option?

Answer (score 0):

for the first problem you need to remove the record rule that prevent the user from seeing other company invoices.

```
setting --> security --> record rules
```

look for the rule that do that and uncheck apply for read if you want the user to see the invoice without having the right to change or delete.
or uncheck all if you want to have full access to them.